# Claim of "are we worse?" connection

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, pinchas, behaalotcha-parsha

I noticed twice there was a group of people who came to Moshe and said: "are we any worse / למה נגרע?" Or: "why should it be worse / למה יגרע?". [Those who were tamei](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.9.7) and the [daughters of Tzelophchad](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.27.4).

Their claim was valid enough for Moshe to ask Hashem what the law should be, and Hashem introduced a new halacha for the masses.

Does anyone comment on this parallel statement?

Comment: https://www.alephbeta.org/course/lecture/parshat-pinchas-how-is-land-ownership-connected-to-the-pesach-sheni-offering

Comment: @IsaacMoses I love Rabbi Fohrman. Should have assumed he picked up on this.

Answer (score 4):

None of the standard Jewish commentaries at either location seem to make note of this.  However, some modern authorities have commented on this connection, such as Rav Amnon Bazak [here](http://www.hatanakh.com/en/node/29234) and Professor Natan Aviezer [here](https://www.biu.ac.il/JH/Parasha/pinchas/abie.html), see also [here](http://bikurim.kipa.co.il/show_art.asp?id=38836#.WzwWN1dofIU) and [here](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%91/).  (Google search results [here](https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%A2%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%99%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%A2&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8))

Edit: Daf al Hadaf to Bava Basra 119b comments on the similarity in words but difference in cantillation.